# How to enable backspace key in IE extension

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, com-interop

I developed a Internet explorer extension using interfaces which are used in [this project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/csieexplorerbar-ba8fe182). All the things works perfectly except backspace capturing during the extension is focused. I have tried by changing IInputObject interface methods but no luck. Any suggestions for solve this.

IInputObject methods I have used are shown below. To be honest I don't know much about how this is working, If someone can explain the process it is also will be a great help.

```
public void UIActivateIO(int fActivate, ref NativeMethods.MSG msg)
        {
            if (fActivate != 0)
            {
                Control nextControl = base.GetNextControl(this, true);
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Back)
                {
                    nextControl = base.GetNextControl(nextControl, false);
                }
                if (nextControl != null)
                {
                    nextControl.Select();
                }
                base.Focus();
            }

        }

        public int HasFocusIO()
        {
            if (!base.ContainsFocus)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public int TranslateAcceleratorIO(ref NativeMethods.MSG msg)
        {
            if ((msg.message == 256) && ((msg.wParam == 9) || (msg.wParam == 117)))
                if (base.SelectNextControl(
                    base.ActiveControl,
                    Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Back,
                    true,
                    true,
                    false))
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            return 1;

        }
```

Backspace is working with shift key but I wanted to make it work without modifier. I have seen that in [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29215/Pretty-IE-Toolbar-in-C) they have used `TranslateMessage (ref msg);DispatchMessage (ref msg);` to implment that. I have tried that also but no luck. Any help to solve this will be great. (Most of the changes i have made to IInputObject methods seems like not effected eg: change of modifer key is not effected. It is an another issue that I am facing.)